# How do I sort this Array in alphabetical order in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

So I have this array:

```
[[21, "Bowling Ball"], [2, "Dirty Sock"], [1, "Hair Pin"], [5, "Microphone"]], [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],[7, "Toothpaste"]];
```

I want to sort the element of this array in alphabetic order accordingly to the second element. So I wanted to be ordered like this:

[[21, "Bowling Ball"], [2, "Dirty Sock"], [1, "Hair Pin"], [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"], [5, "Microphone"]], [7, "Toothpaste"]];

What can I do to accomplish this in javascript?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: As @Nina points out, you have to decide who's locale (alphabet etc) you want to sort by: user's browser's, content's, server's, site's, site's organization's "headquarters's", ….

Answer (score 4):

With a proper array and the use of the second item, you could use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with hint for [Sorting non-ASCII characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_non-ASCII_characters) for [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for comparing strings.

```js
var array = [[21, "Bowling Ball"], [2, "Dirty Sock"], [1, "Hair Pin"], [5, "Microphone"], [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"], [7, "Toothpaste"]];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[1].localeCompare(b[1]);
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Would you mind updating your reference to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=control)? It is quite a bit more reliable than W3S

Comment: Thank you! You could also toss the `#Sorting_non-ASCII_characters` hash on the end of the `Array#sort` link to take it right to the localCompare example if you wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
let stuff = [
  [21, "Bowling Ball"],
  [2, "Dirty Sock"],
  [1, "Hair Pin"],
  [5, "Microphone"],
  [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
  [7, "Toothpaste"]];
```

This can be accomplished easily by sorting the array items by using the `String.prototype.localeCompare()` method to put the items in alphabetical order.

```
stuff.sort((item1, item2) => item1[1].localeCompare(item2[1]));
```